# How to properly update 2 tables, at the same time, in a database?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, database-design, ado.net

Scenario:

I am using visual studio 2010 and I am making a database sample application.  I have to store these spectroscopy files in a database.  These spectroscopy files are loaded into an spectradata object.  I am planning on storing these objects in the database.  The objects have many different attributes (int,double,string, etc).  In addition, the object also includes an array of y-component data values.

I designed my database to be comprised of two tables (one for spectradata object attributes and the other table for the double array points.  I created the first table to have an autoincrement for the ID.

[image: Database design]

Here is some of the code I put together that basically takes these object values and assigns them to the table parameters.

```
SPCFile spc = new SPCFile();
TSpectraData spectra = new TSpectraData();
spectra = spc.LoadSPC(openSPCFile.FileName);

using(SqlConnection mySqlConnect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBLocal"].ConnectionString))
{
      SqlCommand command = mySqlConnect.CreateCommand();
      command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Spectras VALUES"
                                     + "(@DateTime, "
                                     + "@Name, "
                                     + "@Version, "
                                     + "@SerialHighNumber, "
                                     + "@SerialLowNumber, "
                                     + "@Completed, "
                                     + "@SpectrometerID, "
                                     + "@GasCellID, "
                                     + "@Format, "
                                     + "@Apodization, "
                                     + "@PhaseApodization, "
                                     + "@Temperature, "
                                     + "@Pressure, "
                                     + "@NumScans, "
                                     + "@Resolution, "
                                     + "@Gain, "
                                     + "@PathLength, "
                                     + "@FirstPoint, "
                                     + "@LastPoint, "
                                     + "@MaxFrequency, "
                                     + "@MaxLocPoint, "
                                     + "@MinLocPoint, "
                                     + "@NumDataPoints, "
                                     + "@NumDataPhase, "
                                     + "@Step, "
                                     + "@IgramType)";

                //Adding parameters to command
                //Value for ID will be added automatically since it is set to auto increment

                command.Parameters.Add("@DateTime",         SqlDbType.DateTime, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Name",             SqlDbType.NVarChar, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Version",          SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@SerialHighNumber", SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@SerialLowNumber",  SqlDbType.Float, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Completed",        SqlDbType.Float, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@SpectrometerID",   SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@GasCellID",        SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Format",           SqlDbType.SmallInt, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Apodization",      SqlDbType.SmallInt, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@PhaseApodization", SqlDbType.SmallInt, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Temperature",      SqlDbType.Float, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Pressure",         SqlDbType.Float, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@NumScans",         SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Resolution",       SqlDbType.Float, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Gain",             SqlDbType.Float, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@PathLength",       SqlDbType.Float, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@FirstPoint",       SqlDbType.Float, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@LastPoint",        SqlDbType.Float, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@MaxFrequency",     SqlDbType.Float, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@MaxLocPoint",      SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@MinLocPoint",      SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@NumDataPoints",    SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@NumDataPhase",     SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Step",             SqlDbType.Float, Int32.MaxValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@IgramType",        SqlDbType.SmallInt, Int32.MaxValue);
                //Adding values to these parameters
                command.Parameters["@DateTime"].Value = DateTime.Now;
                command.Parameters["@Name"].Value = spectra.Info.Name;
                command.Parameters["@Version"].Value = spectra.Info.Version;
                command.Parameters["@SerialHighNumber"].Value = spectra.Info.SerialHighNumber;
                command.Parameters["@SerialLowNumber"].Value = spectra.Info.SerialLowNumber;
                command.Parameters["@Completed"].Value = spectra.Info.Completed;
                command.Parameters["@SpectrometerID"].Value = spectra.Info.SpectrometerID;
                command.Parameters["@GasCellID"].Value = spectra.Info.GasCellID;
                command.Parameters["@Format"].Value = (short)spectra.Info.Format;
                command.Parameters["@Apodization"].Value = (short)spectra.Info.Apodization;
                command.Parameters["@PhaseApodization"].Value = (short)spectra.Info.PhaseApodization;
                command.Parameters["@Temperature"].Value = spectra.Info.Temperature;
                command.Parameters["@Pressure"].Value = spectra.Info.Pressure;
                command.Parameters["@NumScans"].Value = spectra.Info.NumScans;
                command.Parameters["@Resolution"].Value = spectra.Info.Resolution;
                command.Parameters["@Gain"].Value = spectra.Info.Gain;
                command.Parameters["@PathLength"].Value = spectra.Info.PathLength;
                command.Parameters["@FirstPoint"].Value = spectra.Info.FirstPoint;
                command.Parameters["@LastPoint"].Value = spectra.Info.LastPoint;
                command.Parameters["@MaxFrequency"].Value = spectra.Info.MaxFrequency;
                command.Parameters["@MaxLocPoint"].Value = spectra.Info.MaxLocPoint;
                command.Parameters["@MinLocPoint"].Value = spectra.Info.MinLocPoint;
                command.Parameters["@NumDataPoints"].Value = spectra.Info.NumDataPoints;
                command.Parameters["@NumDataPhase"].Value = spectra.Info.NumDataPhase;
                command.Parameters["@Step"].Value = spectra.Info.Step;
                command.Parameters["@IgramType"].Value = (short)spectra.Info.IgramType;
                mySqlConnect.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                fileChosen = false;
                //Don't have to call connection close due tp using statment
                label1.Hide();
            }
```

Since the ID is auto-increment I don't need to include it in the VALUES statement.  The next step in my process is to add to the data points table.  I plan on reusing the command object and reassigning the command text.  My question is how can take this array of data points and assign them in the other table while keeping the ID concurrent in both tables.  What I assume, is that the relationship basically says "if primary and foreign key match, therefore they are related".

Comment: why not write a stored procedure that does this job for you? Add in a transaction there as well.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: sequence NEXTVAL and CURRVAL are useful. OR keep the value in a variable and use it in both inserts

Comment: Using SQL server. What is a stored procedure? what is meant by transaction? Semi-noob here. lol

Comment: @Randy Since I am not assigned the ID number in the code how am I supposed to get the number to reuse it?  I have the database set up to autoincrment the primary key which is ID.

Comment: change the code so that you query the id number from a sequence - then use it explicitly.

Comment: Ok, what if I have multiple entries in the table? Then I insert.  Then I query attempting to grab the ID.  Now, how am I to specify that I am getting back the correct ID number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming a lot of things here, but, I wish to give this pseudocode.

First, you could retrieve the last inserted autoincrement number (IDENTITY) on your connection using the query `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Second, knowing that number you could easily prepare a loop to insert the datapoints where the parameters are created with dummy values outside the loop and replaced with the effective value inside the loop on the datapoints.

A transaction should be a benefit because, if something goes wrong while looping on the datapoints you don't need to clear the already inserted data

```
// Start a TransactionScope to handle all/or/nothing scenario
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(SqlConnection mySqlConnect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBLocal"].ConnectionString))
    {
          SqlCommand command = mySqlConnect.CreateCommand();

          // Append the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY as a second command on this text.....
          command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Spectras VALUES"
                                         + "(......)"
                                         + ";SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
          mySqlConnect.Open();

          // HERE YOU EXECUTE THE COMMAND AND GET BACK THE LAST IDENTITY USED 
          SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
          if (reader.HasRows)
          {
              reader.Read();
              int spectraID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
              // Ready to start the insert of points

              SqlCommand cmdPoints = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DataPoints " + 
                                      "VALUES (@ID, @IDX, @VAL)", mySqlConnect);
              cmdPoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",spectraID);
              cmdPoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDX",0);
              cmdPoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL",0);

              foreach(DataPoint dp in DataPoints)
              {
                  cmdPoint.Parameters["@IDX"].Value = dp.Index);
                  cmdPoint.Parameters["@VAL"].Value = dp.Value);
                  cmdPoint.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
        }      
    }
    scope.Complete(); // This will write everything on the database

}
```

If you exit due to an exception the scope will not complete and the whole set of records will be discarded

BEWARE: You don't specify the column names in the INSERT INTO command. This means that the framework will try to insert every column including the ID (IDENTITY) and with the value of the first parameter (a datetime?). You should insert the names of the field in the exact order in qhich you pass the parameters.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Spectras " 
                      + "(Name, Version, SerialHighNumber, .......)"
                      + "VALUES (@Name, @Version, @SerialHighNumber, ......)"
                      + ";SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
```

Comment: I think that may work.  Now, what if I have multiple instances of the application accessing the database?  Does the select_scope_identity() function only pertain to what is happening in the current context?

Comment: Updated the answer to include the SCOPE_IDENTITY in the same batch command passed to sql server. This will effectively remove the chance of concurrent access messing around with SCOPE_IDENTITY ([Here a link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)) on the various methods to retrieve the IDENTITY value)

Comment: Community rejected your edit, but you were right, in this version there is no need for the second command. fixed now

Comment: I am getting an error when I run this.  I tried send the command but maybe I am doing something wrong.  

"An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Spectras' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON."

Comment: You didn't insert the column names in the INSERT INTO. This means that the query will try to insert every column including the IDENTITY (ID), this will cause the error because your first parameter is a DateTime that will be inserted in the column ID. I will try to update the answer in a minute

Comment: Ok, I added the column names. Now, after I execute this I get an exception at $int spectraID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]); ---- It says "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.".  There should be data to be read because it confirms that the reader has rows.